# How to stop increment stored array after ajax success using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am storing two input values in an array. The Array values will show in an HTML table. When final save is clicked, all values should save to the database. How do I clear this HTML table when Ajax success on Save(without reloading page) because the next time it is showing the previous array. I don't want to show the previous array. i have tried document.getElementById("result_pay_modedetails").innerHTML = " ";   not at all clear array table.It just continuing array.How to do new array after ajax success?

Here is my function for storing array values in a table.

```
var z = 0;
var x = 0;
var array = Array();
var array1 = Array();

function add_element_to_array() {
    var amtpatvalue = document.getElementById("amount_to_pay").value;
    array[x] = parseFloat(amtpatvalue).toFixed(2);
    array1[z] = $('input[name=pay]:checked', '#paymode').val();
    x++;
    z++;
}

function display_array() {
    var e = "<table id='pay' border=1 style=''>";
    alert(array.length)
    for (var y = 0; y < array.length; y++) {
        e += "<tr>";
        e += "<td><input class='paymodeamt getdata' id='paymodeamt' name='paymodeamt' value='" + array[y] + "'></td><td><input class='storepaymode getdata' id='storepaymode' name='storepaymode' value='" + array1[y] + "'></td>";
        e += "</tr>";
        //var paymentResult = array1[y] + ":" + array[y] + " ";
    }
    e += "</table>";
    document.getElementById("result_pay_modedetails").innerHTML = e;//HTML table will show in this div
    return e;
}
```

ajax function when click final save

```
function saveData() { //save data

    var paymodeamt = [];
    var storepaymode = [];

    $('.paymodeamt').each(function () {
        paymodeamt.push($(this).val());
    });

    $('.storepaymode').each(function () {
        storepaymode.push($(this).val());
    });

    if (parseFloat(advamt) > 0) {

        var getlastID = $('#getlastID').val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "save.php",
            data: {

                getinvoiceid: getlastID,
                getstorepaymode: storepaymode,
                getamount: paymodeamt
            },
            success: function (data) {
                //$('#pay tbody').html('');
                //$("#pay").empty();
                //$("#pay tbody tr").remove(); 
                //$("#result_pay_modedetails").empty();
                document.getElementById("result_pay_modedetails").innerHTML = " ";
                $(".paymodeamt").val(' ');
                $(".storepaymode").val(' ');

            }
        }) //ajax close payment mode
    }
} //end save process
```

Comment: I don't see an `AJAX` reference in your script .. But the way I would clear the html would be `$('#elementID').html('');` Which just clears the element with the id of `elementID` of all `html`

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow . Please edit your question to include the HTML source of the table.

Comment: If you haven't, I suggest looking into ```$.ajax()``` in jQuery documentation: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Have you tried `console.log` to test if you are even getting to the AJAX call ..  And then use `console.log` within the success to ensure you're getting that far .. The syntax within the AJAX call looks ok to me  ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you finish your asynchronous action, you need to reset your variables:

```
        success: function (data) {
            //$('#pay tbody').html('');
            //$("#pay").empty();
            //$("#pay tbody tr").remove(); 
            //$("#result_pay_modedetails").empty();
            document.getElementById("result_pay_modedetails").innerHTML = " ";
            $(".paymodeamt").val(' ');
            $(".storepaymode").val(' ');

            z = 0;
            x = 0;
            array.length = 0; // empties the array
            array1.length = 0; // empties the array
        }
```

A better approach would be to remove these global variables entirely, as global variables will cause you nothing but pain going forward. But that's a bigger issue and beyond the scope of your question.